# Hoffman and Kunze Section 6.8 Number 11

Tags: linear-algebra

What's wrong with the following proof of Theorem 13? Suppose that the minimal polynomial for $T$ is a product of linear factors. Then, by Theorem 5, $T$ is triangulable. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be an ordered basis such that $A=[T]_\mathcal{B}$ is upper-triangular. Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $a_{11},\dots,a_{nn}$. Then $A=D+N$, where $N$ is strictly upper-triangular. Evidently $N$ is nilpotent.

I keep staring at this problem and can't find what is wrong with the proof. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do $A,N$ necessarily commute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is $\boldsymbol D$ [not $\boldsymbol A$ in the comment, sorry], $ \boldsymbol N$ do not necessarily commutes. You could prove, by direct computation, that if $\boldsymbol D = \mathrm {diag}(c_j\boldsymbol I_{n_j})_1^s$ is diagonal and of size $n \times n$, and if $\boldsymbol B \in \mathrm M_n(\mathbb F)$ commutes with $\boldsymbol D$, then 
$$
\boldsymbol B = \mathrm {diag}(\boldsymbol B_j)_1^s,
$$
where $\boldsymbol B_j \in \mathrm M_{n_j}(\mathbb F)$.

The theorem actually states that such operators $\mathcal D, \mathcal N$ could be polynomials in $\mathcal A$, which is pretty strong.